# Java Webservice WSDL loading but not webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, localhost

I'm trying to learn how to create my own web service in Java for my own understanding.

When I got to localhost:9998/calculate?wsdl I can see my wsdl file, but when I got to localhost:9998/calculate I can't see my web service. I just get an error in chrome that says ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE localhost didn't send any data.

Here is my interface:

```
package Webservice;


import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Endpoint Interface
@WebService
public interface Calculate{

    @WebMethod 
    public int add(int x, int y);

    @WebMethod 
    public int sub(int x, int y);

    @WebMethod 
    public int mul(int x, int y);
}
```

Here is my implementation of the interface:

```
package Webservice;
import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Implementation
@WebService(endpointInterface = "Webservice.Calculate")
public class CalculateImpl implements Calculate {

    public CalculateImpl() {

    }

    @Override
    public int add(int x, int y) {
        return (x+y);
    }

    @Override 
    public int sub(int x, int y) {
        return (x-y);
    }

    @Override
    public int mul(int x, int y) {
        return (x*y);
    }
}
```

and here is my publisher:

```
package Webservice;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class CalculatePublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(new CalculateImpl());
        ep.publish("http://localhost:9998/calculate");
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A WSDL represents a SOAP service.  Each service operation requires the HTTP request to be a SOAP call, which is not the same as a plain HTTP GET request made by entering a URL into a browser.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383526 and https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383539 .

Answer (score 0):

Your web service is correct. You need to send a HTTP POST request.

**Option 1**

You could test it with soapUI (https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html). Create a new project using http://localhost:9998/calculate?WSDL

[image]

[image]

**Option 2**

You could also test it from the command line using curl

Create the soap request. I created it on /var/tmp/calculate_add.xml:

```
me@centos> pwd
/var/tmp
me@centos> cat calculate_add.xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://Webservice/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:add>
         <arg0>1</arg0>
         <arg1>1</arg1>
      </web:add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Send the request. ***Note:*** Change the String YourServerIP to your real IP:

```
me@centos> curl -i -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data "@/var/tmp/calculate_add.xml" -X POST http://YourServerIP:9998/calculate
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 Mar 2017 08:55:12 GMT
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:addResponse xmlns:ns2="http://Webservice/"><return>2</return></ns2:addResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Ok, let's say I wanted a page that was localhost:9998/myhtmlpage or something along those lines that was a webpage with two text boxes that called the add method on my web service. Is there a way to do this in java/eclipse? I would probably need some javascript behind the scenes of my html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test webservice thru simple browser. Either you have to write webservice client code or need to use some tool. Postman is one of such tool can be used to test SOAP,REST & any http services.

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/08/22/making-soap-requests-using-postman/